# Is there a simpler shortcut substitution for my models SQL syntax error in browser

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Models:**

```
    function getUserDetail($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_loggedin_user');
    $this->db->where('user_id =',$user_id);

    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

**Error in browser as follows:**
Error Number: 1064

```
SELECT * FROM (`tbl_loggedin_user`) WHERE `user_id` =
```

**Probelm overview**

With my code-igniter site down for maintenance, I need a way to get around this  SQL syntax error in my models file. I've tried as much as I could to get a solution. Looking for any related code scenarios that can append to the solution of relieving my browser error. I could use some advice right about now as to how I should go about replacing the bad code with good code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html), it seems like your query should rather look like this:

```
function getUserDetail($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_loggedin_user');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);

    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, brief and to the point. Stackoverflow does it again!

Answer (score 1):

The least amount of code answer is

```
function getUserDetail($user_id)
{
    return $this->db
           ->get_where('tbl_loggedin_user', ['user_id' => $user_id])
           ->result_array();
}
```